# Kotlin immutable arrays

Tags: arrays, kotlin

Kotlin lists come in separate mutable and immutable varieties, where the former is derived from the latter. But as I understand it, with arrays, there is no separate immutable type per se; instead, an immutable array is declared like `Array<out Foo>`.

Is this correct?

If so, what's the reason for array and list types being designed differently in that regard?

Comment: What would the difference be between an immutable list and an immutable array?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I would expect a small difference in efficiency (list needs to allocate an extra object as well as the underlying array) and in the case where it's a parameter, the ability to take an array as an argument (e.g. vararg).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is correct, `Array`s are all mutable, there's no separate read-only interface for arrays.

The reason for this is that arrays are low-level building blocks that should not normally be exposed in the API or passed across encapsulation boundaries, and in general, there's no reason to use arrays over lists outside data structure implementations and, sometimes, performance-critical code. One should prefer lists and other collections for higher-level operations.

So, given that arrays are usually encapsulated and 'owned' by a single, consistent piece of logic, it was not so practical to introduce a separate type for arrays that doesn't expose mutating functions.